# Azure service fabric - Upgrade stateless service without corrupting schema and database

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We have 2 instances of a stateless service accessing read/writes to a database. Both these services are in separate upgrade domains. In case I have schema changes and one instance upgrades the database schema on startup - how do I ensure that the second instance will not corrupt the data in the interim period where it has not been upgraded.

Is there an out of box solution  that azure service fabric provides?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: We are using Sql Azure

Comment: If you are changing database schema and tables are changed so dramatically so old queries or any DML instruction from another UD that is not updated yet would fail, you have no reason to worry about corrupted data. Any command that could corrupt something would not work. Except if you change some business logic in stored procedure. Are you going to change any stored procedures or is it only tables schema?

Comment: Could be either. While we are making everything backword compatible - in case something slips through the cracks, may cause data corruption.

Answer (score 1):

No, Service Fabric does not have any ready-made solution to this scenario. Comparing it to the scenario of upgrading the state schema (i.e. the classes used for state) of a Stateful Service, the general solution is to try to do append-only, backwards compatible changes to the schema. Any more complex change than that and you need to write some custom mechanism to handle the migration from old to new state schema.

In your case with Stateless Services, if you can keep your database schema changes to append only (add columns with default values etc.) then I would do that. Otherwise you probably need to implement some form of version tracking in the database. Your service instances could then check the db version and if it is higher than its own deployed version, then back-off from that operation and wait for the upgrade.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, block the other instance by checking the schema version. But that leads to down times. I am still looking for a more elegant solution.